# optimal predictor value for multivariate regression in R

Tags: r, regression, statistics

Suppose I have 1 response variable Y and 2 predictors X1 and X2, such as the following

```
Y    X1   X2
2.3  1.1  1.2
2.5  1.24 1.17
......
```

Assuming I have a strong belief the following model works well

```
 fit <- lm(Y ~ poly(X1,2) + X2)
```

in other words, there is a quadratic relation between Y and X1, a linear relationship between Y and X2.

Now here are my questions:

1. how to find the optimal value of (x1,x2) such that the fitted model reaches the maximal value at this pair of value?
2. now assuming X2 has to be fixed at some particular value, how to find the optimal x1 such that the fitted value is maximized?

Comment: I don't see how is it relevant to fitting. After fit is found, you just want to investigate its properties. 1. You have a fit function, and now want to find it's maximum value. 2. For a given X2, maximise `fit(X1,X2)`. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12525/is-there-a-way-to-maximize-minimize-a-custom-function-in-r

Comment: I am new to R. does object fit gives you the explicit function formula? How to maximize these two cases? Thanks

Comment: It returns `lm` object http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lm.html which has coefficients of your variables in it, see some examples here http://data.princeton.edu/R/linearModels.html

Comment: @sashkello. Yes, I know I can use summary to get lm content, now the question is how to get the optimal setting? I have a master degree in statistics, so I do understand what your link says. So I have to explicit extract the coefficients from fit and write the formula out? Thanks

Comment: For 1, do you mean which value of `(x1,x2)` gives the minimum distance between the observed and the fitted value?

Comment: coef(lmfit) will give you a vector of coefficients, which you can multiply by (1, x1, x2) to get the value of your function. This way you create a function you wish to optimize.

Comment: I see, I think this is the only way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an empirical way to do this:

```
# create some random data...
set.seed(1)
X1 <- 1:100
X2 <- sin(2*pi/100*(1:100))
df <- data.frame(Y=3 + 5*X1 -0.2 * X1^2 + 100*X2 + rnorm(100,0,5),X1,X2)
fit <- lm(Y ~ poly(X1,2,raw=T) + X2, data=df)
# X1 and X2 unconstrained
df$pred <- predict(fit)
result  <- with(df,df[pred==max(pred),])
result
#           Y X1        X2     pred
# 19 122.8838 19 0.9297765 119.2087

# max(Y|X2=0)
newdf       <- data.frame(Y=df$Y, X1=df$X1, X2=0)
newdf$pred2 <- predict(fit,newdata=newdf)
result2     <- with(newdf,newdf[pred2==max(pred2),])
result2
#           Y X1 X2    pred2
#12 104.6039 12  0 35.09141
```

So in this example, when `X1` and `X2` are unconstrained, the maximum value of `Y = 119.2` and occurs at `(X1,X2) = (122.8,0.930)`. When `X2` is constrained to 0, the maximum value of `Y = 35.1` and occurs at `(X1,X2) = (104.6,0)`.

There are a couple of things to consider:

1. These are global maxima in the space of your data. In other words if your real data has a large number of variables there might be local maxima that you will not find this way.
2. This method has resolution only as great as your dataset. So if the true maximum occurs at a point between your data points, you will not find it this way.
3. This technique is restricted to the bounds of your dataset. So if the true maximum is outside those bounds, you will not find it. On the other hand, using a model outside the bounds of your data is, IMHO, the definition of reckless.

Finally, you should be aware the `poly(...)` produces *orthogonal polynomials* which will generate a fit, but the coefficients will be very difficult to interpret. If you really want a quadratic fit, e.g. a+ b × x+ c × x<sup>2</sup>, you are better off doing that explicitly with `Y~X1 +I(X1^2)+X2`, or using `raw=T` in the call to `poly(...)`.

Comment: Any easy way to extract the coefficient of a variable in regression object "fit", when we don't know its relative order.  e.g, the coefficient of "x^2" without knowing its position

Comment: In the example above, you would use: `coefficients(fit)["I(x1^2)"]`

Comment: I found I could not extract the coefficient of intercept using your suggested method, other term coefficients are fine. coefficients(fit)["Intercept"]    => NA

Comment: Use: `coefficients(fit)["(Intercept)"]` for the intercept.

Answer (score 0):

credit to @sashkello

Basically, I have to extract coefficients from lm object and multiply with corresponding terms to form the formula to proceed.

I think this is not very efficient. What if this is regression with hundreds of predictors?